# change menu class active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change menu class active when click a submenu. But instead what my code does is that set active the default active menu.

```
$('#menu1').find('li').click(function(){
   //removing the previous selected menu state
   $('#menu1').find('li').removeClass('active');

    //is this element from the second level menu?
    if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('second-level')){
         $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

    //this is a parent element
    }else{
         $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

So for example

```
<ul id="menu1" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active" > <a href="{{URL::to('/')}}">{{ Lang::get('messages.home') }}</a></li>
<li class='dropdown '>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        {{ Lang::get('messages.vehicles') }}
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a> 
                    <ul id = "second-level" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="form-general.html">{{link_to_action('MaintenanceController@vehicle_maintenance', 
                            Lang::get('messages.vehicle_maintenance'),null)}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

when click second level submenu active class is set to home menu (default active meanu) after page refresh. How to set active the menu of submenu?

Comment: You said it yourself : *"after page refresh"*. JavaScript calls in one page will not affect an other pages. You should be doing that (the class check) server side, not client-side.

Comment: first of all there is no second-level class. basically it is id . so your code should be
if($(this).closest('ul').find('#second-level'))

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon could you give me an example how to do this?

Comment: @Amit Kumar  i changed it and still the same after page refresh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon I am using laravel and if I want to check if url is vendi == 'index.blade.php' where vendi is window.location.pathname; how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the URL in the menu item's link to the current URL on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu1 li').each(function() {
        if (location.href.indexOf($('a',this).attr('href'))>=0) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        };
    });
});
```

However, it's probably better to add the class yourself or use server-side code to do so (depending on how your site is generated).

Comment: still the same. after refresh active class is set to default li

Comment: We don't have enough information about your problem, then. Can you reproduce it at http://jsfiddle.net?