# PHP webpage navigation and active page

Tags: php, html, css

i have template.php and i include navigation.php that in separate page to template  i want when i navigate through my website pages to be the page i'm on to be active with css style i want to be linked to css page to take active style link for my links.

here my naviation.php page.

```
   <body>
  <?php 
    $directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $components = explode('/', $path);
    $first_part = $components[1];
     ?>

    <div id="navigation">
<div class="shell">
    <ul>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Home") {echo "active";  } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="Home.php"> <span>HOME</span></a></li>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="About") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="About.php"> <span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="services") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="services.php"> <span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Products") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="products.php"> <span>Products</span></a></li>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="clients") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="clients.php"> <span>Clients</span></a></li>
 <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="contacts") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="contacts.php"> <span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is my css style.

```css
#navigation { background:#4073b9 url(images/navigation.gif) left top repeat-x; height:50px; }
#navigation ul { list-style:none; }
#navigation ul li { float:left; height:42px; line-height:42px;}
#navigation ul li a { float:left; height:42px; line-height:42px; color:#fff; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;  padding:0 0 0 33px;  }
#navigation ul li a span { float:left; height:42px; line-height:42px; padding:0 33px 0 0; }
#navigation ul li a:hover,
#navigation ul li a.active { background:url(images/navigation-active.gif) left top no-repeat; }
#navigation ul li a:hover span,
#navigation ul li a.active span { color:#4073b9; background:url(images/navigation-active.gif) right top no-repeat; }
```

```html
   <body>
      <?php 
        $directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $components = explode('/', $path);
        $first_part = $components[1];
         ?>
        
        <div id="navigation">
 <div class="shell">
  <ul>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Home") {echo "active";  } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="Home.php"> <span>HOME</span></a></li>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="About") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="About.php"> <span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="services") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="services.php"> <span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="Products") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="products.php"> <span>Products</span></a></li>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="clients") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="clients.php"> <span>Clients</span></a></li>
     <li class="<?php if ($first_part=="contacts") {echo "active"; } else  {echo "noactive";}?>"><a href="contacts.php"> <span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
    </body>
```

hope you can help me thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set current page "active" in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I normally do is like this, it's easy and safe.

header.php

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="home") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="home.php"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="about") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="about.php"><span>ABOUT</span></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="services") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="services.php"><span>SERVICES</span></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="products") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="products.php"><span>PRODUCTS</span></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="clients") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="clients.php"><span>CLIENTS</span></a></li>
        <li class="<?php if ($current_page=="contacts") {echo "active"; }?>"><a href="contacts.php"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

index.php (home)

```
<?php
$current_page = 'home';
include('header.php');
?>

/*rest of your page content follows */
```

about.php

```
<?php
$current_page = 'about';
include('header.php');
?>

/*rest of your page content follows */
```

and so on...

**And correct these lines in your CSS:**

Replace this:

```
#navigation ul li a.active { ... }
#navigation ul li a.active span { ... }
```

With this:

```
#navigation ul li.active a { ... }
#navigation ul li.active a span { ... }
```

Comment: i didn't work i think the problem in my css page cause the links work fine but it didn't take the style from css,and that's is my problem but thank you for the help :3