# Make navigation bar active in php include_once tag

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

I have the basic navigation bar for all my pages in header.php so how do it make it active so people know which page they are on via the navigation bar

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="features.php">SMARTRETAIL FEATURES</a></li>
     <li><a href="faq.php">FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</a></li>
     <li><a href="customers.php">CUSTOMERS</a></li>
     <li><a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
     <li><a href="userguide.php">USER GUIDE</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.active {
    background-color: #2676f5;
}
```

Comment: is this pure php or using a cms

Answer (score 0):

if php refer to the answer here [How to set current page "active" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php)

in short

```
// set this above the include of the nav
$activePage = "offnungszeiten.php";

$pages = array();
$pages["index.php"] = "Öffnungszeiten";
$pages["features.php"] = "Sauna";
$pages["faq.php"] = "Frauensauna";
$pages["custom.php"] = "Beauty Lounge";
$pages["feiertage.php"] = "Feiertage";


//menu.php
<?php foreach($pages as $url=>$title):?>
  <li>
       <a <?php if($url === $activePage):?>class="active"<?php endif;?> href="<?php echo $url;?>">
         <?php echo $title;?>
      </a>
  </li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="index.php" class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="features.php"  class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/features.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">SMARTRETAIL FEATURES</a></li>
 <li><a href="faq.php" class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/faq.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">FREQUENTLY ASKED QUESTIONS</a></li>
 <li><a href="customers.php" class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/customers.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">CUSTOMERS</a></li>
 <li><a href="contactus.php" class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/contactus.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">CONTACT US</a></li>
 <li><a href="userguide.php" class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/userguide.php') ? 'active':'' ?>">USER GUIDE</a></li>
```