# No Static Footer or Header

Tags: html

My company just bought out another company and I have to change some links on their site to point to our site.  However, this site doesn't have a static footer or header (as in, each link is recreated on each HTML page).  So instead of changing the necessary files (30+), is there any other way to do a sweeping change?

Thanks.

Comment: The purchased company has 30+ static html pages as a website? Time for a redesign. Anyways, you could use a language like python to open each file and insert the necessary code automatically.

Comment: You could also make a jQuery script to read them and change accordingly, but that's obviously more intrusive than it should be.

Comment: @Polyov Absolutely, but the plan is to redirect some links to us, and slowly but surely just get rid of the other web site.

Comment: One way that is fairly common that I would recommend is to create an `include` file (using a language such as PHP).  See this article: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-include-php-headers-and-footers-on-html-site/ - you'd touch the 30 files to cause them to use the include, but you would only have to do that *once*.

Comment: @cale_b I was thinking about that, but in my head it would take longer than to just do it individually.  But I guess that's before I realized how many static pages there were.

Comment: It would take longer the first time, no doubt.  But the *very first time* you have to change something, it will pay off big time.

Comment: @cale_b Well that's it, unfortunately.  I'm only doing this once.  This site will be sooner or later (I imagine later) scrapped.

Comment: @ThomasHutton - you can of course do what you like.  But my experience is that there's *always* another update.  Whether there was a mistake in the first round of updates, or someone comes along with a new page, or whatever.  Regardless - best of luck!

Comment: @cale_b Can you post your include file as an answer.  I need to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are several methods, the one that I would recommend would be to use a server side [include file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

My recommendation would be to follow these steps, approximately:

1. Copy the header / nav contents from one of your HTML files into a new PHP include file (called, for example, `header.php`).
2. Edit each HTML file, removing the header / nav contents, and including the file - that would look something like this: `<?php require_once 'header.php'; ?>`
3. Repeat for the footer, if that has "common" links and markup.

While this may take longer initially, the very first time you have to make any updates it will pay off.

Lastly, there are ways - if necessary - to (utilizing PHP) make the current nav item have an active class, etc.  That's a bit of a stretch for this answer, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php) may get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to these files on a GNU/Linux machine, use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's|http://oldcompany.com|https://newcompany.net|g' /dir/of/static/files
```

The `-i` flag does infile replacements, so each file under the given path is will be searched for the first URL and replaced accordingly.

Please note that this will just change links like `http://oldcompany.com/team` to `http://newcompany.net/team`. It also does not change links for `https://oldcompany.com` which would require modifications of the sed expression. Please give more information on how the links should be altered so we can provide solutions for your specific problem.