# Bootstrap active nav li item with get urls

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="?orderBy=new">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="?orderBy=old">Link2</a> </li>
<li><a href="?orderBy=best">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="?orderBy=worst">Link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add active class so user knows on what page he is at. 
My best idea is to have li items with unique id and in jquery check if id=1 to set "Link1" with active class.
Even tho this works, I can't stop wondering if there is a better solution, more elegant one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15963757/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have php there,as in your tag, you can compare $_GET values. Something like that:

```
<li <?=$_GET['order_by']=='new' ? 'class="active"' : '';?>>
<a>link</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it server side like cssBlaster21895 has shown, but you can do it client-side with javascript, too.

```css
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0].getElementsByTagName('a'),
    qString = window.location.search;

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (qString == link.getAttribute('href')) {
    link.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    link.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="?orderBy=new">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="?orderBy=old">Link2</a> </li>
  <li><a href="?orderBy=best">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="?orderBy=worst">Link4</a></li>
</ul>
```