# Set current page active and get page data from ID database

Tags: php

Hi can i know how to get id from database if i use this for menu?

Means ***$pages["data.php?id=[This ID retrieve in Database]"] = "Data John";***

and for page data on the top i insert this ***$activePage = "data.php?id=[This ID retrieve in Database/current ID select by user]"***; and this page also have a button menu and set to active in css. My code is below. Help me for my assignment. newbie :(

```
// controller

$pages = array();
$pages["data.php?id=1"] = "Data John";
$pages["data.php?id=2"] = "Data Sauna";
$pages["data.php?id=3"] = "Data George";

$activePage = "data.php?id=2";


// menu.php
<?php foreach($pages as $url=>$title):?>
  <li>
       <a <?php if($url === $activePage):?>class="active"<?php endif;?> href="<?php echo $url;?>">
         <?php echo $title;?>
      </a>
  </li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Your requirement/Question is unclear. Please tell us what is the issue/error or the expected result

Comment: @IndraKumarS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963757/how-to-set-current-page-active-in-php i refer here